# Node.js how to abort file upload when a file is heavier than required - without waiting for the whole file to be uploaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer, formidable

I want to allow, file upload of maximum 3 files, each file is 200kb max, each.

550kb file a,
25kb file b
and 25kb file c is not allowed.

I want to abort the process by the time the server receives 200kb+1bit of the first file.

Otherwise hackers can celebrate...

I don't care if the frontend GUI doesn't get a response header telling the client that the process has been aborted - since validations in backend are made only for hackers - who simply uses my GUI without trying to hack, should not send 550kb at first of all! The GUI was pre-designed to send the proper files anyway.

I have tried to use **formidable** and **multer** (on two different branches).

However the file is getting saved in temp directory of node - which I don't know to get to, this is the path if it tells something:

**/var/folders/sc/fjg8d5j16bnb_9st9h2jb8c40000gn/T/upload_2da9cf165791672f3099372a5e5801da**

Is there a way to do this? maybe could you post a guide in here or show a quick class making this happening with Node.js and express?

I have tried to search at Google but really - found just nothing.

Comment: You can validate on multer as limits: { fileSize: 200 }, Refer : https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#limits

Comment: If a user provided with 3 files - and there allowed to be 3 files, but each of them should be 200kb and the user provided with 3 files 5gb each.
Will multer going to stop when it reaches 200kb+1bit on the first file and abort the process? What about the temp folder, is it contains any files? Should they be deleted or muler takes care of it?

Comment: Multer will restrict before uploading file using file metadata

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr file metadata couldn't be fake by user?